# sending my JSON object from the selected index on a listview to my next activity (android)

Tags: android, json, android-intent

Hey everyone sorry in advance I have been looking frantically for the answer to this question. I know in theory I'm supposed to use

```
i.putExtra("jsonArray", jArray.toString());
```

in my intent but it either can't resolve or is giving me errors.

I'm trying to pass the person's name and the id from the array (the id and name from my query). and pass it so i can use the id in my next query on my next activity.

```
                Person resultRow = new Person();
                //set that person's attributes

                resultRow.id = json_data.getString("id");
                resultRow.icon = json_data.getString("birthday");
                resultRow.name = json_data.getString("name");
                resultRow.address = json_data.getString("address");
                resultRow.city = json_data.getString("city");

                //this is our arrayList object, we add our Person object to it
                arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        //get our listview
        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        //we initialize our fancy adapter object, we already declared it above
        //in the class definition
        aa=new FancyAdapter();

        // here we set the adapter, this turns it on
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the log
            Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());

            // this is the line that prints out the location in
            // the code where the error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    // here is where the magic begins
    //we extend our ArrayAdapter, and use it to create custom views 
    //as well as execute other more complicated functions
    //this time, our ArrayAdapter is an array of Persons, instead of strings like in other tutorials
    class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {
        FancyAdapter() {
            super(ListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            //we call an if statement on our view that is passed in,
            //to see if it has been recycled or not.  if it has been recycled,
            //then it already exists and we do not need to call the inflater function
            //this saves us A HUGE AMOUNT OF RESOURCES AND PROCESSING
            //this is the proper way to do it
            if (convertView==null) {                         
                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                //here is something new.  we are using a class called a view holder
                holder=new ViewHolder(convertView);
                //we are using that class to cache the result of the findViewById function
                //which we then store in a tag on the view 
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));

            return(convertView);
        }           
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name=null;
        public TextView address=null;
        public TextView icon=null;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.birthday);
            birthday=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.favorite_color);
        }
        //notice we had to change our populate from to take an arguement of type person
        void populateFrom(Person r) {
            name.setText(r.name);
            address.setText(r.address);
            icon.setText(r.birthday);
        }
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick=new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i= new Intent(ListActivity.this, bar.class);
            i.putExtra("jsonArray", Person(name).toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: what are the errors you are getting ?

Comment: it not even running, eclipse just keeps telling my the variables wont get resolved like it wont recognize my array object when i try to call the intent

Comment: oops i was just toying with it i was trying to just pass the string name from the object of the person it was actually i.putExtra("jsonArray", jArray.toString());  and I apologize for my haywire responses im brand new to stackoverflow

Comment: i am also totally new to android, im a php developer so the syntax and flow and how/where you call and create classes is different.  i dont know if maybe i was setting my on click listener and the intent in the wrong part of my class and i didnt know if the actual cells had to be created in the program before i can sent the intent and onclick listener as well

Answer (score 1):

You could also implements [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) in your class Person to send the current instance of class Person

Or just send the person's id to the next activity with intent extra and get the Json after to compare the id:

```
intent.putExtra("PERSON_ID", current_person.id);
```

Comment: right that was what i was going to do but eclipse keeps telling me person cant be resolved to a variable  i.putExtra("PERSON_ID", person.id);

Comment: ^^.  put the id in your holder and use it

Comment: class ViewHolder {

     public TextView name=null;
     public TextView address=null;
     public TextView icon=null;
     public TextView id=null;
        
        ViewHolder(View row) {
         name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
         address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.birthday);

};

Comment: icon=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.favorite_color);
         id=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.theid);
        }
        //notice we had to change our populate from to take an arguement of type person
        void populateFrom(Person r) {
         name.setText(r.name);
 
         address.setText(r.address);
         icon.setText(r.icon);
        }
   
    
    }

Comment: private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick=new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
     View view, int position,
     long id)
     {

      
   
    Intent i= new Intent(ListActivity.this, bar.class);
      i.putExtra("extra", String.valueOf(id));
      i.putExtra("PERSON_ID", person.id);
    startActivity(i);
   }